# NoClassDefFoundError while importing a class with an inner class

Tags: clojure, noclassdeffounderror

I'm not being able to import a particular class (`FinanceService`) from a jar. All the others work fine, including the inner-class `FinanceService$Versions`. I'm getting a `NoClassDefFound` exception, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

This exception occurs, paraphrasing an answer I've found here, *when the source was successfully compiled, but at runtime, the required class files were not found*, but I can clearly see it inside the .jar, whose first elements are:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/google/
com/google/gdata/
com/google/gdata/client/
com/google/gdata/client/finance/
com/google/gdata/data/
com/google/gdata/data/finance/
com/google/gdata/client/finance/FinanceService$Versions.class
com/google/gdata/client/finance/FinanceService.class
com/google/gdata/client/finance/FinanceUtilities.class
com/google/gdata/client/finance/PortfolioQuery.class
```

Just to be sure, I rebuilt the jars, and still got the same error. Since it is the only class that both has an inner class and is failing to load, I considered the hypothesis that there must be a special way of loading it, but [this code](http://briancarper.net/clojure/clojure-qt4-demo.clj) proves the contrary. Any idea what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Can we download this jar from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, of course! I've uploaded the jar to http://scorciapino.com/pub/code/gdata-finance-2.0.jar, and, just in case, the project page is at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That jar apparently has lots of dependencies, make sure you have all of them on CLASSPATH when you start Clojure.  Also make sure you aren't mixing versions.  I skipped the download link for `gdata-finance-2.0.jar` that you have up there, and instead downloaded http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/files/gdata-src.java-1.26.0.java.zip from the project page you linked, which came with a ton of jar files in `gdata/java/lib`, one of which was the finance jar.  So I unzipped everything and did this:

```
$ java -cp /path/to/clojure.jar:gdata/java/lib/* clojure.main
Clojure 1.2.0-master-SNAPSHOT
user=> (import '(com.google.gdata.client.finance FinanceService))
com.google.gdata.client.finance.FinanceService
```

This apparently worked.  But now `FinanceService$Versions` doesn't exist.  It doesn't exist in `FinanceService.java` either.  It's probably a different version of the library than what you are using, would be my guess.

If you're getting `NoClassDefFound`, be sure you're paying attention to what class it isn't finding.  `FinanceService` might be missing, but it might also be complaining that one of its dependencies is missing.